# VBA - if columns contains text and another column is a weekday then apply conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, date

[image: Excelfile]

So this is my file. I have this for all the days of the week in one sheet.

What I want to do is use conditional formatting in the rows of 1ST,CUCA,SERVICE ADMIN,2ND,CHAT. This I have figured out but now I want this to only apply on monday to thursday and then other rules for friday, saturday, sunday.

So this is the code I have for the moment

```
Sub SetFormulasFormat()
  
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cl As Range
With ActiveSheet

        
        
    For Each cl In Application.Intersect(.Columns("E"), .UsedRange)
      
        If UCase(cl.Value) = "1ST" And Weekday(cl.Offset(, -2), vbMonday) < 6 Then
            .Range("F" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 1 single cell in same row
            .Range("F" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            
            .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",Y" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=3" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",Y" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            
            .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=4" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
 
            .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, Formula1:="=7" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 0, 128)
            
            .Range("J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 140, 0)
            
            .Range("Z" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=2" 'apply CF rule to 1 single cell in same row
            .Range("Z" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
            
        End If
        If UCase(cl.Value) = "CUCA" Then
            
            .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed

        End If
        If UCase(cl.Value) = "SERVICE ADMIN" Then
            
            .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
        
        If UCase(cl.Value) = "2ND" Then
            
            .Range("F" & cl.Row & ",G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("F" & cl.Row & ",G" & cl.Row & ",H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row & ",X" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        
         End If
         
        If UCase(cl.Value) = "CHAT" Then
            
            .Range("H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=1" 'apply CF rule to 2 different cells in same row (Separate each cell with , like G2,H2...)
            .Range("H" & cl.Row & ",I" & cl.Row & ",J" & cl.Row & ",K" & cl.Row & ",L" & cl.Row & ",M" & cl.Row & ",N" & cl.Row & ",O" & cl.Row & ",P" & cl.Row & ",Q" & cl.Row & ",R" & cl.Row & ",S" & cl.Row & ",T" & cl.Row & ",U" & cl.Row & ",V" & cl.Row & ",W" & cl.Row).FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbRed
                                     
        
        End If
        
    Next cl
    
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific issue or problem?

Comment: I add a new column with a numeric field which tell me how to format the data. Then use usual conditional formatting. You can use as condition an external column

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Weekday` to determine the day of the week and create two `IF` statements, one for <5 and one for >4.  Friday, Saturday and Sunday being days 5,6 and 7.  You can reference the function to determine what you want as your date, column C, today's date, etc.

Comment: Any particular reason you recommend `WorksheetFunction.Weekday` instead of the VBA Function `WeekDay`?

Comment: No, I'll edit.  Was just thinking of user trying the function in a spreadsheet if not familiar with the format.

Comment: I tried it with Weekday but I got an mismatch as you can see in the code above

Comment: Is the data in Column C in a text format?  If you change the format to number, does it show a number equal to a serial number?  4 Jan 21 = 44200 in a number format.